# Opamp wrong output gain

Tags: operational-amplifier, output, gain

I have a circuit like this: 
[image: Multisim circuit]

I am using OP07CP op-amp . V+ and V- are supplied by two 12.2V adapters (which are quite stable!) V1 are supplied using Function Generator

According to what I have learned so far, Vout is equal to V1*2.2/1 = 2.2V1 . Multisim also shows this result . But the problem is that I got the wrong result.

For example :
 If V1 is 0 , the output is ~ -0.56
V output is the same for V1=2.5V
What did I miss here ?

Comment: Your circuit is configured as an **inverting** amplifier. Its gain is -2.2V1 not +2.2V1

Comment: Other than what @brhans said it should work as you indicated. Check your connections.

Comment: Your positive supply shows "12.2V" right near the symbol and "VCC" off to the side. The negative supply is the other way around. Are you sure you're actually supplying -12.2 V to pin 4?

Comment: Sorry for the elementary question, but do you have the other sides of the 12.2V adapters connected to ground or just to each other?

Comment: According to your diagram, there's no connection between your input voltage, and your VCC/VDD for your OpAmp. If that is the case in your "real-world" circuit, the OpAmp can't be expected to give predictable output because you may be exceeding it's Absolute Maximum Ratings. Vin+ and Vin- must be kept between VCC and VDD using some form of biasing.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong sign . Actually i got -0.5x each time . I miss typed it guys. And I you 2 adapter of 12.2V , the ground of the 1st adapater and the 12V-out gate of the 2nd adapter are connected to each other. So this will give 12V and -12V.

Comment: Is the common between the two adapters connected to your circuit ground? eg. to pin 3 of the OP-07

Comment: thank you @SpehroPefhany , you really got the solution to the problem. Thanks

Comment: Don't be so lazy with the schematic.  Showing is a whole screen shot adds a lot of useless fluff around the schematic.  That causes the picture to be shrunk to fit the 640(?) maximum horizontal pixels allowed here, making details hard to see.  See how the schematic should have been properly trimmed in my answer.  If you had done this yourself, you might have notices the negative supply voltage at top yourself.  Neatness and attention to detail matter in engineering!  Fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect the common between the two power supplies (adapters in your case) to your circuit ground:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQX6Zb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Otherwise current through R1/R2/V1 and input bias currents will cause your ground to move around relative to the common point of the two power supplies and will cause problems with common mode input range and output range.

Answer (score 0):

You have the power supplies reversed:

[image]

Or, you have the opamp schematic symbol defined with the power supplies backwards.  Either way, there is a serious problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Instead, they are correct: pin 4 is Vee, and pin 7 is Vcc, see datasheet (also this pinout is very common in single op-amp, 8 pin package).

This happens if you "flip" vertically your symbol, to have the inverting input on the top. (see also the numbers 2, 3, 6 , which are below the pin).

Comment: @Nex: Like I said, either the power supplies are reversed or the symbol is flipped.  Something is wrong either way.  Even if the pinout in the symbol is actually correct, showing the negative supply at top and the positive at bottom is really bad schematic drawing, to the point of being wrong.

Comment: I agree, it creates a lot of confusion, and it is source of errors.